# C# Access Properties of an Object dynamically as fast as possible

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

I'm writing a parser to set Properties of Objects and search for a better way to solve the problem. I will post short examples, normal Segments have more Properties (which is why i search an efficient way to parse).

I have segments which derive from the class ASegment.

```
abstract class ASegment
{
    public Field[] Properties { get; set; }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= Properties.Length) return "";
            PropertyInfo prop = GetType().GetProperty(Properties[index].Name);
            return (string)prop.GetValue(this);
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = GetType().GetProperty(Properties[index].Name);
            prop.SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}

class ExampleSegment: ASegment
{
    public ExampleSegment()
    {
        Properties = new[]
        {
            new Field("Field1",20), //A Field represents different options
            new Field("Field2",10),//For example the Name of the Property
            new Field("Field3",10) //and MaxLength, Repeatable, etc (not needed for my problem, 
                                   // except you know a better way to solve this :)
        };
    }
    public string Field1{ get; set; }
    public string Field2{ get; set; }
    public string Field3{ get; set; }
}
```

Now here is the way i parse the Message:

```
 string text ="ExampleSegment|f2|f3";
 string[] segmentMessage = text.Split('|');
 //I access the right Segment through Reflection. The First part of the Message is always the Segment name.
 ASegment segment = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(Namespace+segmentMessage[0]) as ASegment;
 for (int i = 0; i < segment.Properties.Length; i++)
 {
      if (i < segmentMessage.Length && segmentMessage[i] != null)
          segment[i] = segmentMessage[i];//Here i set the Value
 }
```

Everything works fine, but i think this solution is not very good.

Problem 1: Everytime i create a segment, the Constructor also creates a new instance of the Properties Array.
When I make the Properties Array static in ASegment, and create it in the ExampleSegment with public new static..., i can't access the Properties list through ASegment.

Question: Is there a good way to access and create this Array static.

Problem 2: I think there is a better or faster way to access the Properties of the ExampleMessage class. For Example, I could use Actions instead of the name of the Property to access the Property.

Question: Is it possible to access Properties through System.Action? I only found a way to access Methods through a System.Action array.

I would be glad if you have recommendations for my Problems or other recommendations for my Code =)

kind Regards

Comment: What's the problem with accessing `Properties` when they're static? (what do mean by "i can't access the Properties list through ASegment."?). About a faster way, you can at least cache the `PropertyInfo` objects because the call to `GetProperties` is expensive.

Comment: when Properties is static and i create a different Properties array in every Segment, i would have to access the array like this: ExampleSegment.Properties . Now i access the Properties via ASegment, and there i don't know if i have an ExampleSegment, or another Segment.

Do you probably have an example of how to cache PropertyInfo objects? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can create a static dictionary `Dictionary<Type, Field[]>` in the base class, and an instance property to retrieve the property list for the current type: `public Field[] Properties { get { return ASegment.PropDictionary[GetType()]; } }` (You can think of other solutions, but that's the one which popped to my mind). Of-course, you'll have to populate the `Field` array in a static constructor for each derived class.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I'm using the static constructor of ASegment to create the dictionary and I use the public constructor of ASegment to set Properties (Properties = dict[GetType()];). So I don't have to create Properties in every Segment (        public Field[] Properties { get; private set; }). But It's slower than before :( At least the code is Better than before (I hope so)

Comment: First, as I mentioned before - cache the `PropertyInfo` object (or even, create a delegate from the get and set methods - and cache that delegate). Second, this shouldn't be much slower then before. But, I'll advise to optimize when and where bottle necks are discovered (when the application is already written, and running in environment similar to production), and not before - because it's almost certain that you'll miss the slowing parts, and waste time on parts which run OK.

Comment: Thanks again :P Now it's 25 percent faster. now instead of calling the constructor of field with the name, i call it with propertyInfo. In the static Constructor of the Segments, i add an Entry to the static Dictionary<Type, Field[]> from ASegment. When the Constructor of ASegment is called, i create an reference, which i then use to get and set the values. Yeah i normally do that, but in this case, i have 50 different Segments and it would be a waste of time when i have to change everything :S So i tried to find a good concept before starting to program everything